# Generating a list of combinations from a list of strings with a common separator without reverse duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, combinations

I'm trying to generate a list of combinations from a list of strings with a common separator without reverse duplicates using the code below:

```
separator = "*";
VarList = ["y","lp","ep","rmp","cmp","cp","fp"]


newVarList = [];

currPosition = 0
for currVar in VarList:
    currPosition +=1
    nextPosition = 0
    for nextVar in VarList:
        nextPosition+=1
        if currPosition != nextPosition:
            currText = currVar + separator + nextVar
            if currText not in newVarList:
                newVarList.append(currText)

print len(newVarList)
print(' '.join(map(str, newVarList)))
```

I've managed to generate the combinations and have them listed without brackets or quotes but the reverse duplicates still exist. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @wim For example, A*B and B*A.

Comment: Do you consider `"cpm"` to be a 'reverse duplicate` of `"cmp"`? If so, you are looking for combinations rather than permutations. If not, let us know more clearly.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Apologies, you're right; it should be combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure currPosition is always smaller than nextPosition:
Maybe by changing

```
if currPosition != nextPosition:
```

to

```
if currPosition < nextPosition:
```

That should remove the duplicates.

Comment: That's exactly where I was going wrong, works perfectly now.